# Alter Table and Update column in single stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm am trying to create a stored procedure that adds a new column then sets the column to a value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE alter_then_update 
AS 
    ALTER TABLE table_1 
        ADD bundle_type NVARCHAR(10);

    UPDATE table_1 
    SET bundle_type = 'Small'
```

I keep getting an error that I have an invalid column name of `bundle_type`. I get that the column isn't created yet. Can't I store this in a stored procedure and have the code execute line by line? Doesn't the semi-colon execute in order? I tried using `GO` but the query started to execute instead.

How can I put both of these statements into one procedure?

Comment: Rather than UPDATE, you could add the column with a default constraint value 'Small', specifying `WITH VALUES`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the procedure is *compiled* before it is executed.  I think the only way around this in a stored procedure is dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE alter_then_update AS 
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE table_1 ADD bundle_type NVARCHAR(10);

    EXEC sp_executesql 'UPDATE table_1 SET bundle_type = ''Small''';
END;
```